# Is there any tool to automatically create wiki-like REST API documentation from JSON or Open API?

Tags: rest, documentation, openapi, swashbuckle

I have several services, each one exposed through REST API with ASP.NET Core Web API. I use [Swashbuckle for ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/) tooling in order to automatically generate from my controllers and DTOs all the necessary documentation and visualize it in SwaggerUI. I found this tooling really great, with little annotations on my models and my controllers already provides many features out of the box, such as a UI client to try out the REST API endpoints.
But with this solution each service has its own dedicated SwaggerUI instance and therefore UI.
I would like to offer to my customers a wiki-like documentation with a navigation menu, where, for instance, they can browse sections regarding all the endpoints exposed by my services and have on each page the same features offered by SwaggerUI.

It can be achieved by creating my own web application but I was wondering whether an out of the box solution or some tool that might ease such integration already exists.
I tried [Slate](https://github.com/slatedocs/slate) but I felt like I had to re-invent the wheel in order to automate at least the creation of the basic API documentation, namely controller definition, response definition and descriptions. Does anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this very issue recently working in a microservices architecture, you're absolutely right. There is not need to reinvent the wheel.

I really can't recommend [redoc by Redocly](https://github.com/Redocly/redoc) enough in this case.

Have a look at the [multiple-apis example](https://github.com/Redocly/redoc/blob/gh-pages/examples/multiple-apis/index.html).

Comment: Thank you, indeed Redocly/redoc is what I was looking for and for single Web API microservice it has an out of the box UI available in the NSwag package for ASP.Net Core